# Correct usage of long primitive datatype and its array

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer, type-conversion, fibonacci

I have been coding a question which asks me to `code a modified version of fibonacci.` 
Now although, the code is ready to go, its not working properly, because an int is being returned instead of a long

When the following is used as an input: `0 1 10`
the output is `-9223372036854775807`
intstead of this `84266613096281243382112`

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    static long arr[];

    public static long func(int n,long t1, long t2){
    arr = new long[n+1];
    arr[1]=t1;
    arr[2]=t2;
    return func(arr,n);    

    }
    public static long func(long[] arr, int n){
        if(n==0||n==1||n==2){
            return arr[n];
        }
        if(arr[n]!=0){
            return arr[n];
        }
        arr[n]=(long)(Math.pow(func(arr,n-1),2)+func(arr,n-2));
        return arr[n];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        long t1= s.nextLong();
        long t2=s.nextLong();
        int n=s.nextInt();
        System.out.print(func(n,t1,t2));
    }
}
```

**I am not asking for help with the logic, or solving the question. I want to know where am I going wrong that even though I am using a `long` array the answer being returned is still an int**

Also, any help on **how to handle a long array**, will be great.

Comment: Why are you converting a `long` into an `int`?

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, I don't see where you are converting a long into an int. Why do you say "because of wrong conversion of long into int"?

Comment: Where exactly do you see the conversion?

Comment: I am confused by your comment that says "because of wrong conversion of long into int". As you say, there is no such conversion in your code so this cannot be the problem.

Comment: Why are you starting at index `1` in your array?

Comment: Actually, I am not converting long into int. I chose the wrong words. What I really meant was, "I believe that instead of long being returned, I guess an integer is being returned."

Comment: I suggest you look at the documenation for `pow()`. It returns a `double`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
Yes, that is why I typecasted it.

Comment: Typcasting from a `double` to a `long` might be causing the problem because of the issues involving floating-point precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those wondering, I realized yesterday that the range of long was exhausted and hence, couldnot be used to solve the question. I have used the BigInteger class, and it works.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {


    public static BigInteger func(int n,BigInteger t1, BigInteger t2){
    BigInteger arr[] = new BigInteger[n+1];
    arr[1]=t1;
    arr[2]=t2;
    return func(arr,n);    

    }
    public static BigInteger func(BigInteger[] arr, int n){
        if(n==0||n==1||n==2){
            return arr[n];
        }
        if(arr[n]!=null){
            return arr[n];
        }
        arr[n]=(func(arr,n-1).pow(2)).add(func(arr,n-2));
        return arr[n];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger t1= s.nextBigInteger();       
        BigInteger t2= s.nextBigInteger();       
        int n=s.nextInt();
        System.out.print(func(n,t1,t2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer returned is `not integer` because integer has maximum value of `2147483647` and if value is greater than `integer` value number between `[-2147483647, 2147483647]` is returned. I think there is some problem in logic.

Comment: But my code passes 2 test cases both of which fall within the range of int:

Comment: test case1: 2 1 7
test case2:0 1 5

Comment: Got the problem. Actually you are type casting double value not integer

Comment: Maximum value of `System.out.println((long)Double.MAX_VALUE);` is `9223372036854775807` and your answer surpasses the value of double in Math.pow() which returns `double value`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific to the statement?Which integeral value should I be typecasting?

Comment: Thankyou, for the help. I am afraid, I just checked, the answer is beyond the range of long too. But Thankyou, this was another mistake i was making.

Comment: Cool happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead, because they didn't ask for the entire array but only the nth term.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger t1=in.nextBigInteger();
        BigInteger t2=in.nextBigInteger();
        int n=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++)
        {
            BigInteger temp;
            temp = (t2.pow(2)).add(t1);
            t1=t2;
            t2=temp;
        } 
        System.out.println(t2);
    }
}
```